# Redirection with pipe

Tags: command-line, execute-command, pipe, redirect

I have the following command to be executed.

```
ls > myFile.txt | wc
```

The output of the command shown is

```
0 0 0
```

Why isn't the above command giving the line/word/character count of `ls` output?

Am I missing something? Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is redirected to `myFile.txt` and the `wc` command has therefor nothing to count.

Use that instead:

```
ls | tee myFile.txt | wc
```

The `tee` command prints the input it gets to the file given in the argument **and** to the standard output stream, that is piped again to `wc`.